# Assign different attribute to each column in datatables

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatables

I have my dataTable done successfully

All I have to do is assign the attributes to the columns of this table.

I have the attributes in the array as shown:

```
$attributes = array('7' => array(
  '17' => array(
    'class' => 'editable'
  )
  '18' => array(
    'class' => 'custom_7_18 editable'
  )
)
```

[image]

where `17` and `18` are the ids of `fieldone` and `fieldtwo`.

code for dataTable

```
 $('table.crm-multifield-selector').dataTable({
  "bProcessing": true,
  "asStripClasses" : [ "odd-row", "even-row" ],
  "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
  "sDom"       : '<"crm-datatable-pager-top"lfp>rt<"crm-datatable-pager-bottom"ip>',
  "bServerSide": true,
  "bSort" : false,
  "sAjaxSource": sourceUrl,
});
```

I can't use the `sClass` in datatable as it will assign same attribute to all the `<td>` element. Is there any param to assign different attribute?

Can I assign the attributes from the `$attribute` array to the dataTable?

Or is there any way to assign attribute from the callback function? so that I can use this `$attribute` array in the php file and the dataTable assigns this attribute every time it draws a row?

I've tried this -

```
"fnCreatedRow": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull ) {
   $.each(attributes, function(index, item) {
     //as the number of column can be changed, I can't give 
     //hardcoded values as I found during searching like 
      $('td:eq(2)', nRow).addClass('editable');
   });
}
```

Has anyone come across a situation like this ?

Comment: What you show of `attributes` is a PHP var_dump. Where is `attributes` clientside? How does it look like? Where does it come from, how do you pass it to clientside?

Comment: `attributes` gets calculated at the callback function itself. If I can set it something like which informs the DT to assign it as an attribute ? But for now AFAIK, this isn't possible :(

Comment: You are using `$.each(attributes,...` - what is `attributes` - what does it contain? Where does it come from?

Comment: this js is written in tpl file and I assign attributes as a json_encode of `$attributes` array from php.

Comment: so why not show the `attributes` js, now it is crucial for a solution? Then perhaps we can see the meaning of `17` and `18` as `id`'s ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just fixed this, would like to share here :)-

Assign the attribute for each cell in the call back function itself, i.e, change the cell value to be the array which contains the data as well as the attributes (for eg: class)

```
//$value is the array sent to dataTable
foreach ($value as $fieldId => &$fieldName) {
  if (!empty($attributes[$fieldId][$id]['class'])) {
    //change the fieldName to array containing the attributes and the data part
    $fieldName = array(
      'data' => $fieldName, 
      // as I said in the question, I had $attributes array for the fields ids
      'fieldClass' => $attributes[$fieldId][$id]['class']
    );
  }
}
```

Adjust this to replicate on the dataTable using standard `fnRowCallback`:

```
//Add class attributes to cells
"fnRowCallback": function(nRow, aData) {
   // iterate through each row
   $('td', nRow).each(function(index, element) {
     if (typeof aData[index]=='object') {
       if (typeof aData[index].fieldClass != 'undefined') {
         $(element).addClass(aData[index].fieldClass);
       }

       if (typeof aData[index].data != 'undefined') {
         $(element).html(aData[index].data);
       }
     }
   });
   return nRow;
},
```